# Fixed parameters in a function, c++

Tags: c++, function

I am learning C++ and have the following basic question. Suppose I define a function taking two arrays as arguments, i.e. something like

```
void  function1(const real_1d_array &x, const real_1d_array &params)
```

How can I redefine the function so that I fix the `params` to some values and set the function to be only over `x`?

Comment: default parameter or overload or `std::bind` or lambda.

Comment: What do yoou mean by fix the params? If you always want to have a certain param, then don't make it a parameter, but a local variable instead. Not sure what you actually want to do.

Comment: @Devolus The parameters change later on in the code. However, I need to pass a function that is only over x to an optimizer. In Matlab e.g. this could be done using a function handle @(x).

Answer (score 0):

You can write an higher order function returning a lambda.

```
#include <iostream> 

// Original function
template< class X, class P >
void func_impl(X const& x, P const& param)
{ 
    std::cout << (x + params) << '\n'; // Whatever...
}

// The returned lambda embeds the parameter
template< class P >
auto make_func(P const& param)
{
    return [p = param] (auto x) {
        func_impl(x, p);
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto f{ make_func(42) };

    f(17);
}
```